# Not able to block some websites using /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, ubuntu-14.04, blocking

I want to block social media websites on my computer so that I can avoid distractions and work in peace. One solution I came across was to modify the `/etc/hosts` file to point to `localhost`, so I tried this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   typhus
127.0.0.1   facebook.com
127.0.0.1   linkedin.com
127.0.0.1   youtube.com
127.0.0.1   twitter.com
127.0.0.1   pinterest.com
127.0.0.1   intstagram.com
```

Interestingly, while it blocks Twitter and Pinterest, the rest of the websites are accessible in my browser even though their `ping` points to `127.0.0.1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to block a website through System32/drivers/etc/hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/947466/unable-to-block-a-website-through-system32-drivers-etc-hosts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out on my own: I needed to mention the websites as **www.facebook.com**, and not **facebook.com**.